# Facebook FQL and Graph API in Xcode returning a single video

Tags: objective-c, xcode, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am trying to do a simple query to get a list of all videos in my Facebook account. The FQL query in FQL console (or Graph API console) on Facebook returns the correct number of videos. However, when executing the query (GraphAPI or FQL) from Objective C returns just a single record (video).

On Facebook FQL console:

```
SELECT vid, owner, title, description, updated_time, created_time  FROM video WHERE owner=me()
```

In Objective C (using Facebook's Wishlist sample code):

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: @"SELECT vid, owner, title, description, updated_time, created_time  FROM video WHERE owner=me()", @"query", nil];

NSLog(@"FQL: %@", params);

[facebook requestWithMethodName:@"fql.query" andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
```

When I print the "result" in request:didLoad, it contains just a single video. I am not sure what is causing the problem. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You want the videos that you are tagged in also? or just the ones you've uploaded?

Comment: I am interested in getting both (uploaded by me, and in which I am tagged). A link to the GraphAPI query paths would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will get you all the videos that are on your Facebook account, including the ones that you have been tagged in:

```
NSString *requestPath = @"/me/videos?fields=name,from,description,updated_time,created_time";   
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:requestPath andDelegate:self];
```

I personally only use fql when I have to do multiple queries in a single request. Thats not necessary in this case.

To get the videos that only you yourself have uploaded, you will have to make a request to /me/videos/uploaded instead.

The requested fields above are taken from the video object documentation:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/video/

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you AlexanderNorway. /me/videos/uploaded GraphAPI query you suggested worked! I would also like to know what may be wrong with the FQL query I posted.